# What is a Cat's Eye that was referenced in Monogatari Second Season Episode 24 at 08:35?

Tags: monogatari-series

In Monogatari Second Season Episode 24 at 08:35, Kaiki referred to a person as a Cat's Eye. I found a movie, a road marking, and a jewel. Whatever he is referring to, I don't think it exists in western culture. Does anyone know what Kaiki meant when he referred to the person as a Cat's Eye?

As for what the person did in order to be referred to as a Cat's Eye:

> The person was able to slip an envelope into Kaiki's hotel room. Kaiki says that it shouldn't be possible since 1. they shouldn't know where Kaiki is currently staying, and 2. the hotel room is locked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an old manga series called [***Cat's Eye***](http://myanimelist.net/manga/1932/CATS_EYE), which is about a trio of sisters who are art thieves, and hence presumably skillful enough to break into secured places and steal things, or leave things behind, as may be their wont. I assume this is what Kaiki was referencing.

In the manga, "Cat's Eye" is the name by which the sisters collectively identify themselves (as well as the name of the cafe they operate, among other things).